# -moz- -webkit- ,etc. what to use?

Tags: html, css, webkit

I don't know what the names of these elements are, that's why I have to post a question(I'm sure there are already many answers to it, but I can't find the right results).
On many tutorials and CSS codes I only see "-webkit-" and "-moz-". To this day I've been using(let's take transition):
-webkit-transition
-moz-transition
-ms-transition
-o-transition
transition

Is it better to use all of these, or nonsense?

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: This may help: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/

Comment: If you want your page to be rendered properly on all the browsers, you definately need to add all these prefixes. So obviously, it is better to use all.

Answer (score 2):

All of those are navigator related :

-moz- is for mozilla firefox

-ms- for internet explorer

-webkit- for opera, chrome and safari

They all use those prefixed name to understand the css before the functionality is fully implemented. You can check http://caniuse.com/ to know when to use those.

Comment: Thanks for the caniuse website, it's useful.